# Having problems with css sliding menu

Tags: html, css, menu

I am trying to create a sliding menu docked at the top right corner of the screen, everything seems ok, except the menu isn't sliding as intended.

HTML:

```
<nav class="social-nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="twitter"><a href="#"><img src="images/twitter-up.jpg" /> Follow us on Twitter</a></li>
    <li class="fb"><a href="#"><img src="images/fb-up.jpg" /> Like our Facebook page</a></li>
    <li class="insta"><a href="#"><img src="images/insta-up.jpg" /> Follow us on Instagram</a></li>
    <li class="mail"><a href="#"><img src="images/mail-up.jpg" /> Send us a mail</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

css:

```
body {background:#efefef; margin:0; padding:0;}
.social-nav {
position:absolute; 
top:20px;
right:0;
z-index:999;
font:10px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
} 
.social-nav ul {padding:0; margin:0;}
.social-nav ul li {
list-style:none;
display: block; 
margin: 1px;
width:36px;
text-decoration:none;
transition-duration:0.5s;
-webkit-transition-duration:0.5s;
-moz-transition-duration:10.5s;
}
.social-nav ul li:hover {width:200px;}
.social-nav a{color:rgba(0,0,0,0); display:block; text-decoration:none;width:36px; height:25px; padding:0 0 15px 0;}
.social-nav a:hover{color:rgba(255,255,255,1); display:block; width:200px;}
.social-nav .twitter{background:#00acee;}
.social-nav .fb{ background:#3b5999;}
.social-nav .insta{ background:#5280a4;}
.social-nav .mail a{ background:#fff; color:rgba(0,0,0,0);}
.social-nav .mail a:hover { background:#fff; color:rgba(0,0,0,0);}
```

Comment: what do mean with `as intented` ? What do you expect ?

Comment: What is the intention? I have made a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/2p6h7xq0/ It is sliding but the behaviour is quite clunky

Comment: the intention is to have the bar slide to left on hover, but instead the entire menu slides to the left, but because i made the width 36px, the bars not hovered on shows only a bar of 36px, while the one hovered on shows the intended 200px; i need the bars not hovered on to remain in place and not be acted upon.

Comment: i expect only the bar with the icon hovered-on, to slide left, while the rest stay as they are. example if i hover-on twitter icon, the icon along with its background slides to the left revealing "follow us on twitter", while the facebook, instagram and mail icon remain without sliding until they are hovered-on.

Answer (score 0):

Cant comment, so I updated your fiddle..

http://jsfiddle.net/2p6h7xq0/1/

```
.social-nav:hover li{  width: 200px}
.social-nav li:hover a{color:rgba(255,255,255,1); display:block; width:200px;}
```